# How reliable are answers from this site?

Tags: discussion, statistics

There are many important questions around here, and almost all of them are answered. But are these answers thrustworthy?

For example one may ask about the usage and safety of pesticides in fruits today. He gets an apparently nicely documented answer saying that it's safe. But what if the person behind that answer is selling fruits? :)

Answer (score 20):

The answer is as trustworthy as its source(s). That is the reason why we have a much more rigorous requirement for sources than the answers on many other SE sites.

What that means in practice, is that to determine how good an answer is it is up to the reader to follow the links and evaluate the sources themself.

Comment: Source please..

Answer (score 1):

Counterquestion: Do you believe everything on the internet?

In another word: No. Answers on this site should be treated like everything else: check the sources, verify their reliability and draw your own conclusions.

The advantage of StackExchange is that sources and references are usually provided and that this effort can be done by us collectively.

The more popular this site gets, the more likely it will be that it will be frequented by people with an agenda. We will have to collectively identify them and act accordingly. (See, for instance the [Wiki-PR affair](http://www.latimes.com/business/technology/la-fi-tn-wikimedia-cease-desist-wikipr-20131120,0,4207911.story))

Comment: Answers here *must* have sources, and they will be eventually deleted otherwise. That said, everything else you said is spot on.

Answer (score -1):

There are no right or wrong answers when you ask something subjective. Even if the answer does look right, always question everything. As cliché as it might sound, it is true. You can see the answer through another eyes and you'll learn to be a critical thinker.